# Get id from path variable url Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-urls

I want my end-point to be like  `api/units/:id` so to pass the id as path variable

I have writeen the following code

```
urlpatterns:
path('api/units/', UnitDetailsView.as_view())
```

views.py

```
class UnitDetailsView(APIView):
    http_method_names = ['get']
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = UnitDetailsSerializer

    def get(self, request, id_unit):
        unit = Unit.objects.get(id=id_unit)

        return JsonResponse({
            'id': unit.id,
        }, status=200)
```

However is het a 500 error, because it doesnt recognise the path variable as the id_unit

```
TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id_unit'
```

What is the error and how could i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```
urlpatterns:
path('api/units/<int:id_unit>', UnitDetailsView.as_view())
```

Comment: Should be `id_unit` not `pk` according to OPs view

Comment: I have tried it like this but i get a 404 error and the url can be found

Answer (score 0):

urlpatterns:

```
path('api/units/<int:id>/', UnitDetailsView.as_view())
```

views.py

```
class UnitDetailsView(APIView):
    http_method_names = ['get']
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = UnitDetailsSerializer

    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        unit = Unit.objects.get(id=kwargs["id"])

        return JsonResponse({
            'id': unit.id,
        }, status=200)
```

Comment: I have tried this but when i hit the endpoint ```api/units/:id``` 
I get:
```
"OPTIONS /api/units/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0
Not Found: /api/units/
 "GET /api/units/ HTTP/1.1" 404 2473
```

Comment: Yes, since you need to get id from the url. you should visit `/api/units/1/`